# After resetting Internet explorer 9 can't get proper result

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I had make one function for uploading image, but when I resetting IE9 brower at that time my function is not working properly

```
//for internet explore browser
function checkLength_forIE(node)
{
    if(node.behaviourUrns.length > 0) //this line give me image is attached or not
  {
      if (document.getElementById) {
        if (!clicked) {
          clicked = true;
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        return true;
      }
  }
}
```

Please give me proper solution that when I resetting IE9 browser after how I get the array of uploaded file?
Or any other way to get the uploaded file detail in IE9?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you have misspelled **[behaviorUrns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Some suggestions for your code:

```
//for internet explore browser 
function checkLength_forIE(node) {

  // To keep safe in other browsers, check for beahviorUrns first
  if (node && node.behaviorUrns && node.behaviorUrns.length) {

    // What is the purpose of this line? I think you need to go back to
    // IE 4 to not have getElementById. In anycase, it is a bad inference,
    // test the property you are actually looking for.
    if (document.getElementById) {

      if (!clicked) {
        clicked = true;
        return true;

      } else {
        return false;
      }

    } else {
       return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My ProblemL Objective of this function is to return true if user has uploaded a picture. I cannot find any means to know if user has uploaded the picture or not. I found that node.behaviorUrns.length changing when picture is uploaded.  However this is not working after user put resets IE9 settings.  I need a help if there is another better way to find if user has uploaded picture (photo) or not.